# i want to convert a report which is in text format into a xlsx document. but the problem is data in text file has some missing column values

Tags: java, stream, java-io

typical report data is like this,
[image: Report in txt format]

A simple approach that i wanted to follow was to use space as a delimeter but the data is not in a well structured manner

Comment: Looks like you should use fixed widths to parse, then remove spaces.

Comment: Hint: always come with code. And note: that screen shot ... shows just text. Instead of showing us all of that as image: come with your code and a true [mcve]. In your case, that could be a some sample text with less columns and rows. Focus on the core of your problem, and show us the code that doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 1):

read the first line of the file and split each column by checking if there is more than 1 whitespace. In addition to that you count how long each column is.
after that you can simply go through the other rows containing data and extract the information, by checking the length of the column you are at

(and please don't put images of text into stackoverflow, actual text is better)

EDIT:
python implementation:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

file = "path/to/file.txt"

with open("file", "r") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    columns = re.split("  +", line)
    column_sizes = [re.finditer(column, line).__next__().start() for column in columns]
    column_sizes.append(-1)

    # ------
    f.readline()

    rows = []
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break
        elif line[-1] != "\n":
            line += "\n"

        row = []
        for i in range(len(column_sizes)-1):
            value = line[column_sizes[i]:column_sizes[i+1]]
            row.append(value)
        rows.append(row)

columns = [column.strip() for column in columns]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=columns)

print(df)

df.to_excel(file.split(".")[0] + ".xlsx")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply
yes this is what i have in my mind
and considering i have around 30+ reports and all of them have different structures , is there any tool or library available for this conversion where we could just configure the delimeter condition and let the library handle it?

Comment: @DanialKayani here is a python implementation of what i said, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that export from text to csv is not a practical start, however it would be good for import. So here is your 100% well structured source text to be saved into plain text.

[image]

And here is the import to Excel

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can use google lens to get your data out of this picture then copy and paste to excel file. the easiest way.

or first convert this into pdf then use google lens. go to file scroll to print option in print setting their is an option of MICROSOFT PRINT TO PDF  select that and press print it will ask you for location then give it and use it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: actually its a text file not an image